# On Delphi how to I reference objects that have been created using just one variable?

Tags: object, delphi, memory-management

I was creating a Form with some buttons in runtime in my application and I realized something that's bothering me a lot and I couldn't figure for myself or anywhere in the internet.

Look at the following code.

```
procedure TfrmTest.CreateFourButtons(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer; B: TButton;
begin
  for i := 1 to 4 do
    begin
      B := TButton.Create(frmTest);
      B.Parent := frmTest;
      B.SetBounds(250,(70+(30*i)),75,25);
      B.Caption := 'Button' + IntToStr(i);
      B.Visible := True;
    end;
end;
```

So I just created four buttons at runtime on a form in specific locations. So far so good right?

But now let's imagine that I want to change the Caption property of the first button to "HotPotato"? How do I reference the first button now since I used just one variable to create those buttons? I've been told to store those objects in an array of TButtons or better yet in an TObjectList and these are all fine solutions to this problem. But then one question came to my mind!

Where are those buttons located in the memory? Are the any ways for me to reference them without using arrays or object lists?

Comment: Without a reference, be it in an array, list or stand-alone, you can't reference them. . The owner/parent keeps references though which you can iterate, but it will be more cumbersome.

Comment: And how would that work exactly?

Comment: Setup a loop and iterate them: "for i := 0 to frmTest.Controls.Count - 1 do" if a control is a TButton and if it has the caption you set, then you got it. I trust you can figure out the exact details.

Comment: So it's not that complicated then! Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Assign a unique value to each `B.Tag` - you can then examine `B.Tag` instead of the button's caption - after all, you *may* have more than one button bearing the same caption.

Comment: @Magoo That's an excellent tip thank you!

Comment: Store them in an array or a collection. Why rule out the best solution?

Comment: I wonder why no one mentioned `FindComponent`.

Comment: @Magoo You could also asign unique name to each component instead of using tags. That could help make code more easily redable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal way to keep track of multiple similar object is to use an array.

```
procedure TfrmTest.CreateFourButtons(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer; 
  B: TArray<TButton>; //or array of TButton for older versions
begin
  SetLength(B, 4);
  for i := 0 to 3 do begin
    B[i] := TButton.Create(frmTest);
    B[i].Parent := frmTest;
    B[i].SetBounds(250,(70+(30*i)),75,25);
    B[i].Caption := 'Button' + IntToStr(i);
    B[i].Visible := True;
  end;
  B[0].Caption:= 'HotPotato';
end;
```

When placing buttons on a form this is not strictly needed, the form already uses a list to keep track of child controls placed on it, but you'll need some way to tell the different buttons apart.

You can use the `tag` property for this:

```
  for i := 1 to 4 do begin
    B := TButton.Create(frmTest);
    B.Parent := frmTest;
    B.Tag:= i;
    ...
  end;
  //This will get inefficient if there are many controls on a form.
  for var C in frmTest.Controls do begin  //10.3 syntax.
    if (C is TButton) and (C.tag = 1) then C.Caption:= 'HotPotato'
  end;
```

The `button` is an object and it is thus located on the heap. If you lose its reference you will never find it again. However if it is placed on a parent control, then that parent will keep track of it and you can always get it using [`FindChildControl`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Controls_TWinControl_FindChildControl.html) or the `Controls` list of the form.

`FindChildControl` does a search by name. This requires you to set the name of the control, or it will not work.

```
var B:= frmTest.FindChildControl('Button1');
```

***Note***: FindChildControl only locates immediate children of the control. It can't find a control that is a child of one of the control's children.

This locating children can get complicated if the button is located in a subpanel. Better to use the array or a list to keep track of a range of buttons.

Comment: Nice overview and suggestions.

Comment: Sorry for this, but in this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55136990/how-to-pass-interface-type-to-procedure](question) you answered using an implementation of a record, can I have the name of it (It was erased from my mind and I don't seem to use the right key words)

Comment: @NasreddineGalfout `TVarRec`, part of the system unit.

Comment: God bless you sir.